# How to handle Java URL mappings that are too many to write by hand

Tags: java

For example, I have many city bus lines in the database. And I wrote a page called cityBus.jsp to display which city has which bus line. So I must write URL mappings as many as cities. See below:

```
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>cityBusServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.jiaotong.LoginServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>cityBusServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/Chicago</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>    
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>cityBusServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.jiaotong.CityBusServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>cityBusServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/Paris</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

and so on ...

If write every cities mappings by hand is not beyond my tether, write a page  having information of every city bus lines and write its URL mapping is impossible. Because bus lines of different cities are too many.

So I want to know if these is a method to avoid writing this URL mapping by hand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using use a jax-rs implemention or spring.

You won;t need to map specific urls to java classes in a servlet mapping file.

You include in the class itself.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you mean that you want to map many 'city name' URL patterns to one servlet, than you can achieve this by using a wildcard mapping with '*'.  For example:

```
<servlet-mapping id="...">
    <servlet-name>cityBusServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/citybus/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Which will match /citybus/Chicago and /citybus/Paris (and indeed '/citybus/justaboutanything').  Note that I'd recommend not wildcarding off of the root, so that you can isolate only 'citybus' patterns.  This will allow you to add, say,'/citytrain/*' later, to map to a different servlet for train timetables.

If, however, you mean that you want to map a different servlet per city (as it may be possible to read it from your example), I'd say that in that case you might want to try a different approach, as you'd just be making life very hard for yourself as you move forward.